# given string= welcome to python. I want output as 'welcome-to-python', getting an error in following code

Tags: python

```
def split_and_join(line):
    line=input('enter the string\n')
    w= line.split(' ')
    print('-'.join(w))
split_and_join(line)
```

Here I am getting following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:\python files\practice python\strprg1.py", line 5, in 
>       split_and_join(line)
>   NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: put this `line=input('enter the string\n')` outside the function

Comment: `NameError: name 'line' is not defined` Well, where is `line` defined? Also the function accepts `line` as parameter but immediately overwrites it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that the function is called with a parameter `line` which you did not define before. There are two solutions:

1) Put the definition of `line` out of the function, and before calling the function, as follows:

```
def split_and_join(line):
    w= line.split(' ')
    print('-'.join(w))

line=input('enter the string\n')
split_and_join(line)
```

2) Remove the argument `line` from the function definition, and so call the function without any parameter, as follows:

```
def split_and_join():
    line=input('enter the string\n')
    w= line.split(' ')
    print('-'.join(w))

split_and_join()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line=input('enter the string\n')
```

Should not be inside the function.
Move it before you call it.

Comment: Or remove line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the `split_and_join` what is the `line` variable ? call `split_and_join` without any parameters

```
split_and_join()
```

or put `line = input('enter the string\n')` out side of the function

```
line=input('enter the string\n')
def split_and_join(line):
    ...
split_and_join(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `split_and_join` the variable `line` isn't defined. Given your function, there's no need to pass in the variable as the first thing you do is to read it. This would do just fine:

```
def split_and_join():
    line=input('enter the string\n')
    w= line.split(' ')
    print('-'.join(w))

split_and_join()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a *1-liner*:

```
print('-'.join(input().split()))

# welcome to python
# welcome-to-python
```